# inline delegate event handler Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>
    <a href="/go_to_somewhere">
      x
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Imagine for above elements I have an event for tr, how can I delegate the click when I click on the x link?

I know I can do like below

```
$('a').click(function(e){
e.delegate();
console.log(stop tr click, fire this)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery selector: delegate click event to only tr elements with specific data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187839/jquery-selector-delegate-click-event-to-only-tr-elements-with-specific-data)

Comment: @YoYo Already told you that I'm not adding any event in js for the `a` tag.

Comment: you want to stop executing `tr` event handler when clicked on `a` tag. is that right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I thing you are using the word delegate wrong. Can you explain what you want to achieve with more details, but with the word delegate?  Working example code (instead of pseudo code) of what you have would help too.

Comment: @Venugopal yes, exactly

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) prevents further propagation of the current event.

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("stop tr click, fire this");
};
```